# WPF CornerRadius Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I am trying to animate the borders of my custom button. Animating the `BorderThickness` already works with the `ThicknessAnimation`.

```
<ThicknessAnimation 
 Duration="0:0:0.07" 
 FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
 Storyboard.TargetName="border" 
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" 
 To="2,2,2,2" />
```

Now the type of CornerRadius is `CornerRadius` but there is no such thing as "CornerRadiusAnimation". It could be handled as it was a Thickness e.g. (1,1,1,1) or Int (1).

But as I am starting the Storyboard, it crashes with ThicknessAnimation can't be used to animate CornerRadius.

```
<ThicknessAnimation 
 Storyboard.TargetName="border" 
 Storyboard.TargetProperty="CornerRadius" 
 To="3,3,3,3"/>
```

I really don't want to use keyframes. Is there even a "simple" way to animate the Corners?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You may write your own [animation class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/custom-animations-overview).

Comment: The simplest way would to be use KeyFrames.

Comment: So the problem you're going to run into is it's going to expect to use an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` because the property is an object of attributes, which unlike Points/Doubles will require `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` value stepping which you can do to give the illusion of the equivalent to say an EasingDouble or an EasingPoint Key Frame animation you can do with Points/Doubles. I can give you an example if you'd like but it will be a lot of xaml to accomplish what a few lines with a Point or Double animation could do the same way.